# Batch File to Automate backup folders

Tags: date, batch-file, cmd, directory

So, I currently have a Drobo server that houses a Backup folder for customers that need to have their Hard drive files backed up. I create a folder for each customer in this backup folder. It's our policy to keep these files for our customers for 30 days, after which, need to be deleted. I'm wondering if its possible to make a batch file that can scan the entire Backup folder, each folder for each customer ONLY, not all the files, just the folder by modified date and if it is older than 30 days, move the entire folder that I'll label Delete for further review before deleting. I'm going to make a second batch file to delete all the folders and files once inside that delete folder, but I need the first batch file that scans just the folders' modified date in order to determine if it needs moved first. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: But does the forfiles command work with folders too?

Comment: Yes, it does. Look at `forfiles /?` for cli help.

Answer (score 1):

```
Forfiles /P C:\test\ /D -30 /c "cmd /c move @file c:/delete"
```

just an example of script you might use